# How can I create a sub menu item without creating a category?

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, submenu

I would like to create a dummy submenu like the following without creating a category, since creating a category will result in a url. under the dummy submenu i will have real categories

```
 dummy submenu
      sports wear
      Golf equipments
      etc...
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78824/how-to-make-a-parent-menu-item-which-has-subcategories-not-clickable

Answer (score 2):

this question answer is completely depand on the theme but I will give you answer as `RWD` theme.

you can directly change phtml file for this and add extra `ul/li` structure for your requirement.
 in rwd theme this file located in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`

for your custom theme you can enable template path hint from admin side and check from which file this menu is coming and change that phtml file directly.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the fastest way is to directly edit the html.The function that creates the top menu is in app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php -> function getHtml. If you are using the new responsive web design theme (rwd) it loads app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml and there is the whole html. If you are using the old/default theme it calls _getHtml function in the same file (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php) and there is the whole html. You can check if it loads renderer.phtml by checking if your theme has block with name="catalog.topnav.renderer" in the layout (by default it is layout/page.xml) or calls _getHtml if there is not.

Answer (score -1):

You need to a static block and call it in top menu within top menu nav loop as a parent li for ul